# Python to Windows command prompt interface

Tags: windows-7, python

Is there a way I could send commands to Windows command prompt Python?

What I am looking to do is make a Python app on the desktop which receives commands through sockets from another computer/mobile app.

These commands are then passed on to Windows command prompt for execution.

Using Windows 7.

Comment: Do you mean the real MS-DOS, or the Windows Command Prompt? (The latter is **not DOS**. It's a Windows program.)

Comment: Windows command prompt..

Comment: are you just interested in `execution, do not care how it works behind the scenes` or do you really _need_ the console (`cmd.exe`)?

Comment: @akira: terminology - `cmd.exe` is a _shell_, it parses commands. A console displays them and their output on screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use subprocess module

```
from subprocess import call

call(['cmd', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdin='...', stdout='...')
```

eg:

```
call(['dir', '/W'])
```

Read more here [Subprocess management](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Sometimes, `os.system` can be a better choice - for example, if you have a complete command line and do not want to modify it (which Akash's question seems to be like.)

Comment: @grawity: `subprocess.Popen()` and there you have `os.system()`

Comment: @akira: My point was about `os.system("dir /w")` versus `call(["dir", "/w"])` - splitting the input just to have it rejoined later, and execution via shell. Although I was wrong - I forgot about `Popen(..., shell=True)`, which _does_ accept a string command.